# 'npm install -g' cannot find 'Roaming\npm\node_modules\' directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've just downloaded and installed nodejs to my new machine but neither 'npm install -g' nor 'npm install' command works. It gives ENOENT error. I check the path that gloabally installed packages, namely 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules' folder, and the error says it could not find 'lib' or 'bin' folder but all the folders created by command missing the first letter. The npm error I get down below is shown when try to install typescript globally. I couldn't seem to find a solution, does anyone have any idea what should I do? Thanks in advance.

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-21dd751b\bin\tsc'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-21dd751b\bin\tsserver'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-21dd751b\lib\cancellationToken.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-21dd751b\lib\cs\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-12T12_33_04_656Z-debug.log
```

[See folders' screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spdi4.png)

Comment: I have solved this issue by creating another user in my computer with only English characters. I don't know how they are related but my previous user had non-english characters (İ <- this boy)  so creating a new one was way to go.